# Touch and hold - iPhone cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, touch

I am writing a game and when a user touches the left side of the screen the player moves left, when they touch the right hand part of the screen the player moves right.

Currently the player only moves when you first touch the screen, I want the force to be applied for as long as the user holds their finger on the screen... I cant seem to find a API call for this.  What do I have to do?

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self handleFrankMove:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self handleFrankMove:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self handleFrankMove:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know how you implemented the move, but on touchesBegan, you could start a CCMoveTo action (the edge of the screen) on the sprite, and on ccTouchesEnded, you could stopAllActions on the sprite (or stop the specific action if you were careful to keep an handle to it). Again, many ways to skin that cat, which to use will depend very much on the overall gaming logic and UI strategy you are implementing.

EDIT: here is a way that does not rely on CCActions

when: onTouchesBegan:

```
[self schedule:@selector(keepPushingFrank:) interval:.2]; // interval up to you, experiment
```

when: onTouchesEnded or onTouchesCancelled

```
[self unchedule:@selector(keepPushingFrank:)]
```

when: onTouchesMoved:

```
[self computeFingerLogicforTouch:_frankTouch]; // you may need this to control
                                               // behaviour in keepPushingFrank
```

and add a method like so:

```
-(void) keepPushingFrank:(ccTime) dt{
    // do your thing with box2D to change forces
    // on Frank. you may want to setup some iVars
    // to compute 'finger intention' when it moves
    // and apply physics accordingly (dont know your 
    // app).

}
```

Comment: Hey Yves - I am using Box2d and apply an impulse inside `handleFrankMove`